# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException thrown in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I was writing my parser and I am getting an awkward error.
One of my rules is like the following:

```
operatorTerm[ReadOptions Options, int priority] returns [Term t]
@init
{
int p = priority;
Term t2 = null;
Term t = null;
CompoundTermTag f = null;
}     
    : {testFY($Options, $priority)}?
      a=op[$Options, p]     {f = $a.tag;}
      b=term[$Options, p]   {$t = $b.t; $t = createTerm(f, $t); }
    | {testFX($Options, $priority)}?
      d=op[$Options, p]     {f = $d.tag;}
      e=term[$Options, p-1] {$t = $e.t; $t = createTerm(f, $t);}
    ;
```

This will throw the following error an using the alias ANTLR4

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 199, Size: 199
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at org.antlr.v4.automata.ATNSerializer.serialize(ATNSerializer.java:201)
at org.antlr.v4.automata.ATNSerializer.getSerialized(ATNSerializer.java:375)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.model.SerializedATN.<init>(SerializedATN.java:46)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.model.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:96)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.ParserFactory.parser(ParserFactory.java:92)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.OutputModelController.parser(OutputModelController.java:165)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.OutputModelController.buildParserOutputModel(OutputModelController.java:114)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateParser(CodeGenerator.java:169)
at org.antlr.v4.codegen.CodeGenPipeline.process(CodeGenPipeline.java:73)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:422)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

Now if I chope off a few lines from the code this would compile. Making this new rule has thrown this exception. Also, If I chope off a few lines from this rule itself the exception won't be thrown.

Is it because the size of my grammar has become very large ?
Unable to figure this error out.

Also, I am experiencing no such error even if I trim off some other independent rule. Is there a limit to the size of a grammar file ?

My grammar file is around 800 lines.

Comment: ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.0

Comment: Its definately 4.0 and as I said chopping off some other rules would make this work. Its the length of the grammar file that is not letting it compile. You can take a look at my github repo where you can find my complete grammar file. Also, definately using 4.0, I had installed the 4.0-complete-jar:
https://github.com/rishabhgarg/gnuprologjava-1/blob/parser/src/gnu/prolog/io/Parser_ANTLR4/Parser_Subset/TermParser.g4

Comment: You can run antlr on the file by following the above link to encounter this error.

Comment: I just scrolled through your grammar on Github, and saw this: `['E','e']` (and more like them). You should realize this matches one of `"'"` `"E"` `","` or `"e"`. You probably want: `[Ee]`, or the old fashioned `'E' | 'e'`

Comment: Yes I will correct that. The ANTLR community is really helpful ! Thanks Bart, your tutorials were very helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in a specific version of the ANTLR 4 tool. You can report bugs to the project issue tracker on GitHub:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Note: I cannot reproduce this issue in the latest source code, which will be available as ANTLR 4.1 released at the end of this month.

Comment: So that means I have no way but to switch my compiler compiler ? I had almost got through with my grammar file.
Can I probably expect it to be addressed in ANTLR 4.2 ?

Comment: @RishabhGarg By my statement, I meant it appears to be already fixed and will be officially available in the 4.1 release. You could also build the tool from source so it works in the meantime.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry for misinterpreting your comment. Thank you very much. Really helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried 4.8 and it worked, hope this helps you too.